# ubuntu 15.04 - bluetooth not detecting nor being detected - acer aspire

Tags: bluetooth, 15.04, acer, atheros

I've been trying to get the issue solved elsewhere but nothing worked out, installed all possible packages but still nothing. I got a Acer Aspire V13, just installed Ubuntu 15.04, bluetooth icon is displayed but neither recognizes nor is recognized anywhere. I've also tried with a different bluetooth manager and still nothing. Needless to say, I'm quite of a newbie to Ubuntu.

Output of lslsb:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04ca:300d Lite-On Technology Corp. Atheros AR3012 Bluetooth
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please add output of "lsusb" terminal command to your post.

Comment: Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b469 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04ca:300d Lite-On Technology Corp. Atheros AR3012 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add information there.

Answer (score 2):

Your bluetooth chip is not supported by the kernel yet.

Here is the [Bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1394368).
You can vote there that the bug affects you too. There is a temporary solution there. But it is too technical for a common user.

I sent a few patches upstream to add some of these devices, which have been applied. But in this case also some firmware should be added. I wrote to kernel maintainers, but it will take some time to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware linux-headers-generic build-essential
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/xu80svavlazttaf/bluetooth-3.19.tar.gz
tar xpvf bluetooth-3.19.tar.gz
cd bluetooth
cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Module.symvers Module.symvers
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD modules
sudo cp btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
sudo cp ath3k.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
```

And see if it works after a reboot, if it doesn't show the results of `dmesg | grep -i firmware` and `dmesg | grep -i bluetooth`